# Deducing whether elements are prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, gaussian-integers

Let $ \alpha_1 = 3 + 2\sqrt{-2}, \alpha_2 = 1 + 2\sqrt{-2}$, how do I deduce if these elements are prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$?

I've tried showing that they aren't irreducible, which in turn would show that they aren't prime, but I'm not making any headway.

Is there a standard way of tackling a problem like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider $N(\alpha_1)=3^2+2\cdot2^2=17$ and $N(\alpha_2)=1^2+2\cdot2^2=9$.

You now need to prove these properties for $N$:

- $N(\alpha \beta) = N(\alpha) N(\beta)$
- $N(\alpha) = 1$ iff $\alpha$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$
- If $N(\alpha)$ is a prime, then $\alpha$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

Therefore, $\alpha_1$ is irreducible, because $N(\alpha_1)=17$ is prime.
Since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a PID because it is Euclidean, being prime is equivalent to being irreducible.

To handle $\alpha_2$, we need to consider the elements that have norm $3$. These are exactly $\pm 1 \pm \sqrt{-2}$. We find that
$
1+ 2\sqrt{-2} = (-1 + \sqrt{-2})(1 - \sqrt{-2})
$ and so $\alpha_2$ is reducible and so not prime.

Comment: Does this imply that they are primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$? If so, how?

Comment: Shouldn't $N(\alpha_2) = 9?$

Comment: So $\alpha_1$ is irreducible in the ring and hence prime because it is a UFD?

Comment: It only shows they're irreducible. there remains to show $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ is principal.

Comment: @Bernard You mean a UFD.

Comment: Actually, $1+ 2\sqrt{-2} = (-1 + \sqrt{-2})(1 - \sqrt{-2})$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: It's the same for Dedekind rings.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, oops, thanks!